# How to load an image to an axes

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I want to load an image from a particular folder to an axes when I push a button in my MATLAB GUI. I have tried this code, it lets me select the picture I want but it does not load it to the axes. Can someone assist me on this please?

```
[File_Name, Path_Name] = uigetfile()
fullImageFileName = fullfile(Path_Name, File_Name);
Selected_Image = imread(fullImageFileName );
imshow([Selected_Image ,handles.axes1])
```

Comment: Use `imagesc` instead: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html

Comment: Make sure you set the current axes properly before using any plotting functions. I suspect that this code doesn't result in an error because it loads the image to some other axes. Bottom line: before `imshow` \ `imagesc` do `set(hfig,'CurrentAxes',hAx);`